$P(X_1 = X_{(1)})$ for non-identically distributed random variables $X_1,\cdots, X_n$ : Probability of a sample becomes a specific order statistic
Let $X_1,\cdots X_n$ be independent normal random variables with means $\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n$ and unit variances. And let $X_{(1)}:=\min_iX_i,\cdots, X_{(n)}:=\max_iX_i$ be their order statistics. What is the probability that $X_1$ is the smallest? i.e. What is $P(X_{(1)}=X_1)$? Or more generally, what is $P(X_{(k)}=X_i)$?
I know that even though the $X_i$s are independent, the $X_{(j)}$s are not independent and $X_{(j)}, X_i$ are not independent either and I have no idea what their joint density function looks like. If this is too much to ask, is there any reasonable approximation in terms of $\phi, \Phi$ or papers on this topics?  Thank you so much in advance.

@geetha290krm that was a typo, i meant to say $X_{(j)}, X_i$ are not independent, I edited just now, thanks

Let $N_{-i}$ denote the set including $1,\dots,n$ excepting $i$. Then, for independent $X_1,\dots,X_n$ with continuous cdfs $F_{X_1},\dots,F_{X_n}$ we have
$$\mathbb P \left (X_{(k)}=X_i \right )= \sum_{S \subseteq N_{-i}: |S|=k-1}\mathbb E \left (\prod_{t\in S}F_{X_{t}}(X_i)\prod_{t\in N_{-i}\setminus S}(1-F_{X_{t}}(X_i)) \right ). $$

The above is obtained by noting that the event $X_{(k)}=X_i$ occurs if and only if $k-1$ of $X_1,\dots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\dots,X_{n}$ take values less than $X_i$ and the others take values greater than $X_i$. To get the formula, the conditional probability given $X_i=x_i$ is first computed, which is for fixed $S$ with $|S|=k-1$
$$\mathbb P \left (\bigcap_{t\in S}(X_{t} < x_i)\bigcap_{t\in N_{-i}\setminus S}(X_{t} > x_i) \right )=\prod_{t\in S}\mathbb P (X_{t} < x_i)\prod_{t\in N_{-i}\setminus S}P (X_{t} > x_i)$$
and then the expectation is taken over $X_i$.

When $X_i \sim \mathcal N(\theta_i,1), i=1,\dots,n$ are independent, we have
$$\mathbb P \left (X_{(k)}=X_i \right )= \sum_{S \subseteq N_{-i}: |S|=k-1}\mathbb E \left (\prod_{t\in S}\Phi (Z+\theta_i-\theta_t ) \prod_{t\in N_{-i}\setminus S} \left (1-\Phi (Z+\theta_i-\theta_t) \right) \right ) $$
where $Z \sim \mathcal N(0,1).$

When $X_1,\dots,X_n \sim X$ are iid whose cdf $F$ is continuous such as normal distribution, we have
$$\mathbb P \left (X_{(k)}=X_i \right )= \binom{n-1}{k-1}\mathbb E \left (F(X)^{k-1}(1-F(X))^{n-k} \right )=\binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{\Gamma (k)\Gamma (n-k+1)}{\Gamma (n+1)}=\frac{1}{n} $$
in which the known result $F(X) \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$ is used. The above could be obtained by symmetry.

Hi could you please give a proof or add a reference as to how you arrive at the result?

@Ishigami I just added more details on how I obtained the formula. Hope it is helpful!

Thank you so much for your help!

Not a full answer, but note that
\begin{align}
    P&(X_1 = X_{(1)})
     = P(X_1 \leq X_i \text{ for } i=2,\dots,n) \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{x_1}^\infty \cdots \int_{x_1}^\infty f_{X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) dx_n \cdots dx_2dx_1 \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{x_1}^\infty \cdots \int_{x_1}^\infty f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2) \cdots f_{X_n}(x_n) dx_n \cdots dx_2dx_1 \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1}(x_1) \int_{x_1}^\infty f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_2 \cdots \int_{x_1}^\infty f_{X_n}(x_n) dx_n \ dx_1 \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1}(x_1) P(X_2>x_1) \cdots P(X_n>x_1) \ dx_1
\end{align}
and, for $i=2,\dots,n$,
$$
P(X_i>x_1) = 1 - \Phi(x_1-\theta_i).
$$
